# is.null returns false despite fo being TRUE in R

Tags: r, null, lapply, sapply

i have a variable :

```
x$value
[[1]]
NULL
```

but when i run `is.null(x$value)` i get:

```
is.null(x$value)
[1] FALSE
```

how is this possible? How can i fix this? i am using this inside an `sum(sapply((data$iteration), FUN = function(x) {ifelse(is.null(x$value), 0, x$value)}), na.rm = TRUE)` an getting an error:

```
Error in sum(sapply((data$iteration), FUN = function(x) { : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `x$value` is a list containing one element which is `NULL`, hence `x$value` is not `NULL`. You need to use `x$value[[1]]` to access this list, then you get that `is.null(x$value[[1]])` is `TRUE`.

Comment: but i am using sapply, which takes the list input. What i am not understanding is why i am getting the error inside thn sapply?

Comment: Does it really take the list as input or a list of lists? The error seems to say that the latter is the case. Could you provide reproducible data?

Comment: a list of lists, thats correct. I basically want to replace the NULL with 0

Comment: @Nneka You'll need to update the anonymous function (the argument for `FUN`) in your `sapply` statement.  When dealing with `x` (a `list` of `list`s), your anonymous function must "look inside" `x` for its first element `$value` (a `list`), and then look inside `$value` for _its_ first item `[[1]]` (here `NULL`).  Like so: `function(x) {ifelse(is.null(x$value[[1]]), 0, ...})`.  What comes next (in my `...`) will depend on what you want to happen to an `x` with a nested `NULL`.